# How to modify json without creating any pojo in java

Tags: java, json

We have a json response as part of rest request; 
which is like 0.90MB in size.. for every request hit;
response structure as follows :

```
{
"catg" : "catlist",
"ticketList": 
    {
    "dynamicID1" : {  => //I have to change this id; with what is there in the db
        reto: "00121",
        tickets: 677, => //I have to change this id; with what is there in the db
        slots: {
            dynamicslot1: {
            prop1 : "change this data",
            prop2: "change this data"
            }
         }
        },
    "dynamicId2" : {
        reto: "00121",
        tickets: 677,
        slots: {
            dynamicslot1: {
            prop1 : "change this data",
            prop2: "change this data"
            }
         }
        },

        --------------
        -------------- // like this 1000's of records are there in the response
        --------------
        --------------
        --------------
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest me, without creating any pojo's (as the request hit happens in very frequent; I don't want to create it) how can I achieve this;

**After parsing this, huge payload, I want to return this as a response**

Sample code snippet; appreciate that.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by pojo

Comment: Java pojo classes...usually we do create pojo to map actual json with java objects

Comment: @Basil Battikhi pojo is short for `Plain Old Java Object`

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to create any pojo , then use jackson ObjectMapper and deserialize response as Map.class.
You will get bunch of Map/List/{Integer,String,etc} structures which you might access. 
Accessing main members will be like 
 "catg" -> response.get("catg")

If you use intellij idea - set a [breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html), click OPTION-F8 (on my mac)

And discover your structure on the go.

Answer (score 0):

try to play around with json libraries such as https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java. With that you can easily grab via key-value your requested data fields and add/change/remove

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputString);
String n = obj.getString("name");
```